# Given a pathname, how can I tell whether the object is a directory or a file using the Java File API?

Tags: java

Given the absolute path as a variable String pathname, how can I do the following using the Java Class File? The answers as far as I know are in parenthesis, please confirm.

1. get the size of the file/directory? (I'm not sure)
2. test if the absolute path even leads to something that exists? (File.exists(pathname), which should return a boolean true if it exists, boolean false otherwise)
3. see if this is this a file or directory? (File.isFile(pathname), which returns a boolean true if the pathname leads to a file, false otherwise. file.isDirectory(pathname), which returns a boolean true if the pathname leads to a directory, false otherwise)
4. see the last date modified? (File.lastModified(pathname), which returns a long number which I already have the method for to convert to a specific date

A related but separate question: is there something that is a "file", like a .doc, .jpeg, .mpeg, .mp3, .xml, .* that will fail both isFile and isDirectory tests? If so, how can I distinguish between an empty folder and a folder with a file that fails both isFile and isDirectory tests? I'm asking because on the File class documentation, it states the following for isFile: Tests whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a normal file. A file is normal if it is not a directory and, in addition, satisfies other system-dependent criteria. Any non-directory file created by a Java application is guaranteed to be a normal file.

Comment: for file or directory check this http://www.java-examples.com/determine-file-or-directory

Comment: The "system-dependent criteria" refers to things like UNIX's sockets, named pipes, or special files (/dev/null). Any file that represents data written on the disk is a normal file, basically.

Answer (score 5):

```
File f = new File(path);
// Get size of file (not a directory though)
f.length();
// Check if file exists
f.exists();
// Check if file is directory
f.isDirectory();
// Check if file is file
f.isFile();
// Last modified date
f.lastModified();
```

Reference: [JavaDoc for java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

If you want the size of a directory, you'd have to combine these methods while you traverse the directory you want to compute the size for, or you could use a third party library like `FileUtils` in [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) which has a [`sizeOf`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#sizeOf%28java.io.File%29) method that apparently handles size of directories as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something that is a "file", like a .doc, .jpeg, .mpeg, .mp3, .xml, .* that will fail both isFile and isDirectory tests?

No.  Those are all regular files. If it is a file, it will pass the `isFile` test.

The things that are not "normal files" or directories are things like device files and named pipe files.  The `java.io.File` cannot accurately distinguish these ... or symbolic links.

If you want to be able to do operating system specific things, take a look at Java 7's `java.nio.file` package and specifically the [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class.